# Reception started: not attempting while running veins_inet example

Tags: veins, inet

I am using new version of veins and inetmanet 4.2. The example of veins and inetmanet work but at the example of veins_inet the message not received and I don’t know why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us some code so we can help. Also have a look at [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&q=stackoverflow+how+to+ask)

Comment: Which software versions are you using (beside inetmanet 4.2)? It would be particularly interesting to know the INET version.

Comment: I deleted the INET from my workspace, I use omnetpp-5.1.1 version. thanks